# I have uploaded phpmyadmin on my server via FTP, but I am not able to access it

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

To access mysql database from browser I upload phpmyadmin on my server but its not accessible, please check [here](http://aartisaree.com/phpMyAdmin/)

Its Centos 7.0 server

HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Check the error logs to know what's behind that error 500

Comment: Also this question is within the gray area off ontopic here? As with question seams to be about general software and server configuration?   iam think this question is more suitable for https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com or